# How to create ndarray::ArrayView with custom strides?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I am facing a slice of numbers and want to create an `ndarray::ArrayView` out of this slice (without copying).
In the `ArrayView`, I want to include 2 numbers, then skip one, and so on. For example:

```rust
use ndarray::{ArrayView1, ShapeBuilder};

let numbers = &[0.0, 1.0, 10.0, 2.0, 3.0, 10.0];
let shape = // Some shape
let view = ArrayView1::from_shape(shape, numbers);

// Expected output for `view`:
// [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

Is there any way to set `shape` reaching the desired output?
Normal strides didn't work because they use a fix step size.

I also tried creating a `2x3` `ArrayView2` out of `numbers`, then splitting the last column, and then flattening the array, but this cannot be done without copying because splitting breaks the memory layout.

I hope that it's possible to accomplish what I am trying to do.

Comment: I think there's only one stride per dimension, so you would need to use ArrayView2 like you said.

Comment: @nnnmmm as I said, I couldn't get a ArrayView1 out of the ArrayView2 without copying

Comment: I know, just confirming that if you need an ArrayView1, you're out of luck.

Comment: So I am probably out of luck, the project doesn't allow me to change the architecture so easily

Comment: Do you really need to work with strides? If you only need to take two skip one and so on, then you are probably better off with iterators. Cool thing about Rust is that everything is really performance optimized to the bone, and you probably should not worry about copying too much. Further even if you managed to do what you want you will most likely be needing to work with references to floats, which is the same cost as copying them to new vec, so yeah...

Comment: @TheCoolDrop the data in `numbers` is a bytes buffer, which is a field of a struct, in real, its length is very large. The codebase relies on using arrayviews of this buffer at multiple points and performs calculations with them, which would be more complicated when using iterators. Introducing iterators would basically break 50% of my codebase. It would be so nice if there was any way to create an ArrayView with the shown desired structure on the slice (which is owned by a struct).

Comment: @TheCoolDrop or is it possible to create an ArrayView out of an iterator?

Comment: Look at [the definition for `ArrayBase`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/src/ndarray/lib.rs.html#1228-1242). `D` is essentially a list, so `ArrayBase` stores a list of dimensions and a list of strides. For `ArrayView1`, `D` basically ends up as `[usize; 1]`, so you can only store a single length and stride. To answer your question, sadly what you are asking for is not possible with `ArrayView1`, it doesn't even have the literal storage space for that kind of info.

Comment: @Coder-256 thanks, I am willing to give you the 100 rep bounty if you can formulate this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayView1` is a type alias for `ArrayBase`. [The definition for ArrayBase](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.14.0/src/ndarray/lib.rs.html#1228-1242) is:

```rust
pub struct ArrayBase<S, D>
where
    S: RawData,
{
    /// Data buffer / ownership information. (If owned, contains the data
    /// buffer; if borrowed, contains the lifetime and mutability.)
    data: S,
    /// A non-null pointer into the buffer held by `data`; may point anywhere
    /// in its range. If `S: Data`, this pointer must be aligned.
    ptr: std::ptr::NonNull<S::Elem>,
    /// The lengths of the axes.
    dim: D,
    /// The element count stride per axis. To be parsed as `isize`.
    strides: D,
}
```

`D` is essentially a list, so `ArrayBase` stores a list of dimensions and a list of strides. For `ArrayView1`, D basically ends up as `[usize; 1]`, so you can only store a single length and stride.

To answer your question, sadly what you are asking for is not possible with `ArrayView1`, it lacks the storage space to hold multiple strides.